# how to get liferay portal License EE

Tags: liferay, portal

I want to use liferay portal in my work, i searched in their website but i don't found a clear price for liferay portal or clear way to get license
can any one help me to know how to get liferay portal EE License and what price of it please

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Liferay Enterprise Subscription. Have a look at [Subscription Services](https://www.liferay.com/subscription-services)

From there you can request a quote.